# loop invariant for simple algorithms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, invariance

The following is an algorithm which finds the maximum value in a list of integers, and I want to prove that it is correct by using a loop invariant.

```
algorithm max(list A[0..n − 1])
x ← A[0]
i ← 1
while i < n do
if A[i] > x then x = A[i]
i ← i + 1
return x
```

I really struggle when it comes to finding appropriate loop invariants, so any tips regarding this would also be appreciated.

Anyway, for the above algorithm I have (tentatively) come up with a loop invariant as follows:

> $x \ge A[i-1]$

I am not sure how to actually use this to prove the correctness of the algorithm, or even if the invariant I have come up with is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `x == max(A[0..i-1])` as the loop invariant, positioned immediately after the increment to `i` (last line of `while` loop). To make it even easier to prove that the invariant holds on each pass through the loop, you can use more assertions within the loop body:

```
algorithm max(list A[0..n − 1])
x ← A[0]
i ← 1
while i < n do
    ## x == max(A[0..i-1])
    if A[i] > x then x = A[i]
    ## x == max(A[0..i]) 
    i ← i + 1
    ## x == max(A[0..i-1])

## x == max(A[0..n-1])
return x
```

It's then obviously true that once the loop has terminated, `x == max(A[0..n-1])`.

Comment: I think this was what I was trying to imply when I was coming up with my invariant..I only did $[i-1]$ because it is fairly obvious that it is true for all previous $i$. Does it make a huge difference which invariant you use?

Comment: As long as at the end of the loop you can prove the assertions that you want to hold, no :) So in practice you'll prefer invariants which make that easier. I don't think `x ≥ A[i-1]` is that helpful, because once the loop is done, all you know is that `x ≥ A[j]` for all `j = 0..n-1`, and from this you can't conclude that `x` is the max of the `A[j]`.

Comment: Why can't we conclude that $x$ is the max of $A[j]$? If $x$ is equal to any element from $A$, then it is still a maximum, because order wouldn't really matter. And if $x$ is greater than $A[j]$ then we're done..Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Somehow the invariant has to guarantee that `x is among A[0..i-1]`. Just saying that `x ≥ A[i-1]` doesn't give you that.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop invariant is correct. To use it in a proof, you must say when it is correct and for which values it is correct. In your case, you begin with $x=A[0]$ so the loop invariant is true before each iteration of the loop. It is not enough to say $x\ge A[i-1]$ because that just says that $x$ is at least as big as it was on the last iteration. You must state that this is true for all previous $i$. In your case it is because of the transitivity of the ordering operation.

Then, after the last iteration, you conclude that $x\ge A[i-1]$ for all $i$ and therefore, $x$ must be the maximum.

Comment: What do you mean by the "transitivity of the ordering operation"?

Comment: $a\le b$ and $b\le c$ implies $a\le c$

Comment: Ah, so basically saying that loop invariant is true for all previous $i$ because $x$ gets replaced with a new value if we come across a value in the set that is larger?

Comment: I don't see how this fairly weak invariant helps in proving that the function actually computes max. It could compute max+17 and the invariant would still be true.

Comment: Yes. On each subsequent iteration you claim that not only is $x$ at least as big as the previous one but that $x$ is at least as big as all previous ones. You need that for the final assertion which will be that $x$ is at least as big as all of them.

Comment: @BrianO $x$ is only taking values from $A$. I suppose one could ask, "how do you know this doesn't compute a number bigger than the max?", but this is the basic schema of loop invariant proofs.

Comment: Yes but the invariant does *not* capture the fact that `x` is among the `A[j]`.

Comment: @BrianO You are correct. It is an easy thing to restate the invariant and that makes for a much more elegant proof. But I really believe the spirit of this question was to find out how to use an invariant in a proof, not the details of the proof.

Comment: @JohnDouma Fair enough :) Thinking about it a little more, if we used `x ≥ A[i-1] and x is among A[0..i-1]`, then at the end of the loop we could conclude `x ≥ all A[j] and x is among A[0..n-1`, but you'd have to do an induction to establish the first part of that, and the whole statement is just an obscure way of saying `x = max(A[0..n-1]`.